# Mysql count joined fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, count

I have 3 tables: accounts, comments and followers

In account I track user info, in comments their comments and in followers, who are they following. I want to create a query where I get basic info of the account, a count of comments and a count of followers. I have a query and is not working:

```
SELECT 
    a.company, 
    a.firstname, 
    a.lastname, 
    a.title, 
    a.email, 
    a.zipcode, 
    a.created, 
    a.newsletter, 
    COUNT(c.id) comments, 
    COUNT(f.id) follows, 
    a.linkedinid 
FROM accounts a 
LEFT JOIN comments c ON a.id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN followers f ON a.id = f.user_id
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: missing `group by` while using aggregate functions.

Comment: what should I group by? a.id?

Comment: yes in addition make `a.id` as a part of the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think there are 2 issues.

Firstly you have no GROUP BY clause so it will bring back the counts for everything (one row returned), rather than one row with the counts per account. The account details would be from an undefined row.

Secondly you just COUNT(c.id) / COUNT(f.id). If an account has multiple follows and multiple comments then it will get every combination of those followers and accounts, so the counts would apply to the number of combinations. For example 2 comments and 3 followers would give 6 combinations, and both counts would be 6.

Fixing these by adding a GROUP BY and also adding DISTINCT to the COUNTs gives:-

```
SELECT 
    a.company, 
    a.firstname, 
    a.lastname, 
    a.title, 
    a.email, 
    a.zipcode, 
    a.created, 
    a.newsletter, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) comments, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) follows, 
    a.linkedinid 
FROM accounts a 
LEFT JOIN comments c ON a.id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN followers f ON a.id = f.user_id
GROUP BY a.company, 
    a.firstname, 
    a.lastname, 
    a.title, 
    a.email, 
    a.zipcode, 
    a.created, 
    a.newsletter, 
    a.linkedinid
```

Note that in MySQL it is not necessary to GROUP BY all the non aggregate fields as long as the others are dependent on a field that in in the GROUP BY. However most other flavours of SQL will fail if you do this so to me it is best practice to put them all in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    a.company, 
    a.firstname, 
    a.lastname, 
    a.title, 
    a.email, 
    a.zipcode, 
    a.created, 
    a.newsletter, 
    COUNT(c.id) comments, 
    COUNT(f.id) follows, 
    a.linkedinid 
FROM accounts a 
LEFT JOIN comments c ON a.id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN followers f ON a.id = f.user_id 
GROUP BY f.user_id
```